# How well does the strong nuclear forces cancel out over large distances?

Tags: nuclear-physics, strong-force

Motivation: I was wondering if by any chance gravity could not be a "non-force", but instead be a residual of all other forces that is generated when you put together a bunch of particles with slight imbalances.

Actual question: So I was considering how well the strong nuclear force go to zero and becomes negligible over large distances. Could a lot of nucleons put together not amount to an actual measurable attractive force (which isn't gravity)?

And specially if anyone has calculated the intensity of this. I tried some googling to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Photons, which don't undergo strong interaction, are still affected by gravitational field. This has been experimentally seen in e.g. [gravitational lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lensing). This means that gravitational interaction, even if emergent, doesn't emerge from the strong interaction.

Answer (score 4):

The [strong nuclear force,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) i.e. the force holding the nuclei of atoms together,does not extend further than a fermi

> The nuclear force (or nucleon–nucleon interaction or *residual strong force*) is a force that acts between the protons and neutrons of atoms. Neutrons and protons, both nucleons, are affected by the nuclear force almost identically. Since protons have charge +1 e, they experience an electric force that tends to push them apart, but at short range the attractive nuclear force is strong enough to overcome the electromagnetic force. The nuclear force binds nucleons into atomic nuclei.

The [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) fits the data very well [with the forces described by the theory](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html), and there is no *mainstream physics* possibility of of making gravitation an emergent force.

italics mine.

It is already a spill over force from the strong force between quarks, which grows stronger with distance, the force that binds the quarks inside the proton and neutron.

Answer (score 4):

The strong nuclear force goes to zero *exponentially fast* beyond nuclear distances. It doesn’t need to be “cancelled” to go to zero, and it goes to zero far too fast to explain the inverse-square force of gravity.